# Performing Chalitza during Tisha B'Av

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Can one wear the leather Chalitza shoe during Tisha B'Av, despite the prohibition of wearing leather shoes?

(You might think this applies as well to Yom Kippur, but it states in [Beitza 36B](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.36b.10) that Chalitza can't be performed on Shabbos or a holiday (like Yom Kippur), which seemingly shouldn't affect Tisha B'Av, since it isn't a "full holiday" in the sense of prohibiting Melacha.)

Comment: I can only imagine this being relevant in some case of Iggun, like the brother is leaving town indefinitely that day? Pretty farfetched.

Comment: עשה דוחה אפילו לא תעשה דאורייתא לכן ביוה''כ כנראה יותר, ק''ו בת''ב.

Comment: @kouty if so yibbum too!

Comment: @DoubleAA yes. But for Aba Shaul e.g. Mitsvat Chalitsa Kodem. anyways may be I don't  understand what you are meaning

Comment: @kouty, is doing chalitza the type of mitzvah where we say asei doch lo tasei? Besides, efshar likaim shneihem, wait till tonight. Anyways, if it's mutar, it's because wearing the chalitza shoe is not for comfort, similar to a traveler.

Comment: Can you explain iggun @DoubleAA

Comment: @Moshe Suppose there's only one brother and he has to leave town on Tisha Bav on a dangerous boat journey. If she doesn't do chalitza now, then the brother will leave and his boat may sink and she'll never be able to marry again since no one will know for sure if he died or not. Or suppose there are two brothers: one probably died in a shipwreck but no one knows for sure, and the other is scheduled to be executed that day by the evil antisemitic king. If they don't do chalitza now then she'll be similarly stuck.

Comment: So why's that far fetched? @DoubleAA

Comment: It's a highly specific case that has probably never happened.