# May one perform Chaliztah in the Temple?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

May one perform the Mitzvah of Chalitzah in the Beis HaMikdash, even though this involves wearing a leather shoe, which is generally prohibited due to the holiness of the area?

Comment: Why do you think it should be permitted?

Comment: @Chatzkel *Aseh docheh lo saaseh*

Comment: @pcoz that’s only if there’s no other choice

Comment: Actually @pcoz it's aseh and aseh here

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119817/759